# Maven/JBehave build issue

Tags: maven, jbehave

When attempting to use the Maven plugin with JBehave, I am getting a build error that says
Plugin org.kohsuke:access-modifier-checker:1.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.jenkins-ci:annotation-indexer:jar:1.4 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository

This is everything that happened in the terminal minus some of the reports generated:

```
dhcp-10-126-9-165:jbehave-3.8 DeeWu$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] JBehave
[INFO] JBehave Core
[INFO] JBehave Ant
[INFO] JBehave Maven Plugin
[INFO] JBehave Hudson Plugin
[INFO] JBehave Jenkins Plugin
[INFO] JBehave Navigator
[INFO] JBehave Gherkin
[INFO] JBehave ODF
[INFO] JBehave Google
[INFO] JBehave Groovy
[INFO] JBehave Scala
[INFO] JBehave Guice
[INFO] JBehave PicoContainer
[INFO] JBehave Spring
[INFO] JBehave Weld
[INFO] JBehave Archetypes
[INFO] JBehave Simple Archetype
[INFO] JBehave Groovy Archetype
[INFO] JBehave Guice Archetype
[INFO] JBehave Pico Archetype
[INFO] JBehave Spring Archetype
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building JBehave 3.8
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ jbehave ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ jbehave ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/pom.xml to             /Users/DeeWu/.m2/repository/org/jbehave/jbehave/3.8/jbehave-3.8.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building JBehave Core 3.8
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ jbehave-core ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-core/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ jbehave-core ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 20 resources
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ jbehave-core ---
[INFO] Compiling 185 source files to /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-    core/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ jbehave-core     ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 7 resources
[INFO] Copying 15 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ jbehave-core --    -
[INFO] Compiling 78 source files to /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-core/target/test-    classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.8.1:test (default-test) @ jbehave-core ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-    core/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.jbehave.core.ConfigurableEmbedderBehaviour
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.875 sec
Running org.jbehave.core.configuration.AnnotationBuilderBehaviour
Tests run: 15, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.423 sec
Running org.jbehave.core.configuration.AnnotationFinderBehaviour
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.062 sec
Running org.jbehave.core.configuration.KeywordsBehaviour
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec
Running org.jbehave.core.configuration.ParanamerConfigurationBehaviour
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.027 sec
Running org.jbehave.core.configuration.PropertyBasedConfigurationBehaviour
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.016 sec
Running org.jbehave.core.configuration.UnmodifiableConfigurationBehaviour
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.088 sec
Running org.jbehave.core.embedder.ConcurrencyBehaviour
Using controls         EmbedderControls[batch=false,skip=false,generateViewAfterStories=true,ignoreFailureInStories=f    alse,ignoreFailureInView=false,verboseFailures=false,verboseFiltering=false,storyTimeoutInSecs    =1,threads=1]
Running embeddable org.jbehave.core.embedder.ConcurrencyBehaviour$ThreadsStories
Processing system properties {}
Using controls     EmbedderControls[batch=false,skip=false,generateViewAfterStories=true,ignoreFailureInStories=f    alse,ignoreFailureInView=false,verboseFailures=false,verboseFiltering=false,storyTimeoutInSecs    =1,threads=1]

(BeforeStories)

Running story org/jbehave/core/embedder/a_long.story

(org/jbehave/core/embedder/a_long.story)
Scenario: 
Mauro starts counting to 3
Mauro says 0 Mississippi (0 millis)
Mauro says 1 Mississippi (1001 millis)
Story org/jbehave/core/embedder/a_long.story duration of 2 seconds has exceeded timeout of         1 seconds
When Mauro counts to 3 Mississippi (FAILED)
(java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted)
STORY CANCELLED (DURATION 2 s)

Running story test+dir/dummy.story

(test+dir/dummy.story)
Scenario: 



(AfterStories)




[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ jbehave-core ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-core/target/jbehave-core-3.8.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (package-resources) @ jbehave-core ---
[WARNING] Parameter tasks is deprecated, use target instead

[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
  [zip] Building zip: /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-core/target/jbehave-core-            resources.zip
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.5:attach-artifact (attach-artifacts) @ jbehave-core     ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ jbehave-core ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-core/target/jbehave-core-3.8.jar to     /Users/DeeWu/.m2/repository/org/jbehave/jbehave-core/3.8/jbehave-core-3.8.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-core/pom.xml to     /Users/DeeWu/.m2/repository/org/jbehave/jbehave-core/3.8/jbehave-core-3.8.pom
[INFO] Installing /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-core/target/jbehave-core-    resources.zip to /Users/DeeWu/.m2/repository/org/jbehave/jbehave-core/3.8/jbehave-core-3.8-    resources.zip
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building JBehave Ant 3.8
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ jbehave-ant ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-ant/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ jbehave-ant ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-    ant/src/main/resources
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ jbehave-ant ---
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-ant/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ jbehave-ant     ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-    ant/src/test/resources
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ jbehave-ant ---
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-ant/target/test-    classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.8.1:test (default-test) @ jbehave-ant ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-    ant/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.jbehave.ant.EmbedderTaskBehaviour
Using executor service Mock for ExecutorService, hashCode: 1234403385
Mapping stories as embeddables using embedder Mock for Embedder, hashCode: 1464447632
Found class names : []
Mapping stories as paths using embedder Mock for Embedder, hashCode: 1750442808
Found story paths: [org/jbehave/ant/stories/first.story,     org/jbehave/ant/stories/second.story]
Generating stories view using embedder Mock for Embedder, hashCode: 142077827
Reporting stepdocs using embedder Mock for Embedder, hashCode: 848649429
Running stories as Embeddables using embedder Mock for Embedder, hashCode: 1717173025
Found class names : [org.jbehave.ant.stories.Embeddable1,     org.jbehave.ant.stories.Embeddable2]
Running stories as paths using embedder Mock for Embedder, hashCode: 1477356634
Found story paths: [org/jbehave/ant/stories/first.story,     org/jbehave/ant/stories/second.story]
Running stories with annotated embedder runner
Tests run: 16, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.255 sec
Found class names : [org.jbehave.ant.stories.Embeddable1,     org.jbehave.ant.stories.Embeddable2]

Results :

Tests run: 16, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ jbehave-ant ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-ant/target/jbehave-ant-3.8.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ jbehave-ant ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-ant/target/jbehave-ant-3.8.jar to     /Users/DeeWu/.m2/repository/org/jbehave/jbehave-ant/3.8/jbehave-ant-3.8.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-ant/pom.xml to     /Users/DeeWu/.m2/repository/org/jbehave/jbehave-ant/3.8/jbehave-ant-3.8.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building JBehave Maven Plugin 3.8
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ jbehave-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-maven-plugin/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-plugin-plugin:2.7:descriptor (default-descriptor) @ jbehave-maven-    plugin ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to read mojo metadata.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: java
[INFO] Mojo extractor for language: java found 10 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: bsh
[INFO] Mojo extractor for language: bsh found 0 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ jbehave-maven-    plugin ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-maven-    plugin/src/main/resources
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ jbehave-maven-plugin     ---
[INFO] Compiling 11 source files to /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-maven-    plugin/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ jbehave-    maven-plugin ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-maven-    plugin/src/test/resources
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ jbehave-    maven-plugin ---
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-maven-    plugin/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.8.1:test (default-test) @ jbehave-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-maven-    plugin/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.jbehave.mojo.EmbedderMojoBehaviour
Using executor service Mock for ExecutorService, hashCode: 257798932
[info] Mapping stories as embeddables using embedder Mock for Embedder, hashCode:     971277631
[debug] Searching for class names including [**/*StoryMaps.java] and excluding []
[info] Found class names: []
[info] Mapping stories as embeddables using embedder Mock for Embedder, hashCode:     142077827
[debug] Searching for class names including [**/*StoryMaps.java] and excluding []
[info] Found class names: []
[info] Mapping stories as paths using embedder Mock for Embedder, hashCode: 1717173025
[debug] Searching for story paths including [**/stories/*.story] and excluding []
[info] Found story paths: [org/jbehave/mojo/stories/first.story,     org/jbehave/mojo/stories/second.story]
[info] Mapping stories as paths using embedder Mock for Embedder, hashCode: 1477356634
[debug] Searching for story paths including [**/stories/*.story] and excluding []
[info] Found story paths: [org/jbehave/mojo/stories/first.story,     org/jbehave/mojo/stories/second.story]
[info] Generating stories view using embedder Mock for Embedder, hashCode: 176271867
[info] Reporting stepdocs using embedder Mock for Embedder, hashCode: 1067398966
[info] Reporting stepdocs using embedder Mock for Embedder, hashCode: 115841081
[info] Running stories as embeddables using embedder Mock for Embedder, hashCode:     713879274
[debug] Searching for class names including [**/stories/*.java] and excluding []
[info] Found class names: [org.jbehave.mojo.stories.Embeddable1,     org.jbehave.mojo.stories.Embeddable2]
[info] Running stories as embeddables using embedder Mock for Embedder, hashCode:     424162811
[debug] Searching for class names including [**/stories/*.java] and excluding []
[info] Found class names: [org.jbehave.mojo.stories.Embeddable1,     org.jbehave.mojo.stories.Embeddable2]
[info] Running stories as paths using embedder Mock for Embedder, hashCode: 1006753184
[debug] Searching for story paths including [**/stories/*.story] and excluding []
[info] Found story paths: [org/jbehave/mojo/stories/first.story,     org/jbehave/mojo/stories/second.story]
[info] Running stories as paths using embedder Mock for Embedder, hashCode: 2077036671
[debug] Searching for story paths including [**/stories/*.story] and excluding []
[info] Found story paths: [org/jbehave/mojo/stories/first.story,     org/jbehave/mojo/stories/second.story]
[info] Running stories with annotated embedder runner
[debug] Searching for class names including [**/stories/*.java] and excluding []
[info] Found class names: [org.jbehave.mojo.stories.Embeddable1,     org.jbehave.mojo.stories.Embeddable2]
[info] Running stories with annotated embedder runner
[debug] Searching for class names including [**/stories/*.java] and excluding []
[info] Found class names: [org.jbehave.mojo.stories.Embeddable1,     org.jbehave.mojo.stories.Embeddable2]
[info] Unpacked site to target/jbehave/view
[info] Unpacked core to target/jbehave/view
[info] Unpacked site to /var/folders/qp/l1knq1p930x0mb2f8wq1_4b00000gn/T/jbehave/view
[info] Unpacked core to /var/folders/qp/l1knq1p930x0mb2f8wq1_4b00000gn/T/jbehave/view
[debug] Artifact property artifactId not allowed by values [jbehave-site-resources,     jbehave-core]
Tests run: 28, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.015 sec

Results :

Tests run: 28, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ jbehave-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-maven-plugin/target/jbehave-    maven-plugin-3.8.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-plugin-plugin:2.7:addPluginArtifactMetadata (default-    addPluginArtifactMetadata) @ jbehave-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ jbehave-maven-plugin -    --
[INFO] Installing /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-maven-plugin/target/jbehave-    maven-plugin-3.8.jar to /Users/DeeWu/.m2/repository/org/jbehave/jbehave-maven-    plugin/3.8/jbehave-maven-plugin-3.8.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-maven-plugin/pom.xml to     /Users/DeeWu/.m2/repository/org/jbehave/jbehave-maven-plugin/3.8/jbehave-maven-plugin-    3.8.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building JBehave Hudson Plugin 3.8
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ jbehave-hudson-plugin ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-hudson-plugin/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ jbehave-hudson-    plugin ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ jbehave-hudson-plugin     ---
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to /Users/DeeWu/src/jbehave-3.8/jbehave-hudson-    plugin/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- access-modifier-checker:1.4:enforce (default-enforce) @ jbehave-hudson-plugin     ---
[WARNING] The POM for org.jenkins-ci:annotation-indexer:jar:1.4 is missing, no     dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] JBehave ........................................... SUCCESS [1.930s]
[INFO] JBehave Core ...................................... SUCCESS [2:05.653s]
[INFO] JBehave Ant ....................................... SUCCESS [6.222s]
[INFO] JBehave Maven Plugin .............................. SUCCESS [20.093s]
[INFO] JBehave Hudson Plugin ............................. FAILURE [23.540s]
[INFO] JBehave Jenkins Plugin ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] JBehave Navigator ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] JBehave Gherkin ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JBehave ODF ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JBehave Google .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JBehave Groovy .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JBehave Scala ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JBehave Guice ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JBehave PicoContainer ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] JBehave Spring .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JBehave Weld ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JBehave Archetypes ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] JBehave Simple Archetype .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JBehave Groovy Archetype .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JBehave Guice Archetype ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JBehave Pico Archetype ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] JBehave Spring Archetype .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3:20.245s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 11 08:55:35 CDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.kohsuke:access-modifier-checker:1.4:enforce (default-    enforce) on project jbehave-hudson-plugin: Execution default-enforce of goal     org.kohsuke:access-modifier-checker:1.4:enforce failed: Plugin org.kohsuke:access-modifier-    checker:1.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.jenkins-    ci:annotation-indexer:jar:1.4 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local     repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has     elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the     following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]     http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :jbehave-hudson-plugin
```

Any help getting this error fixed would be great!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that instead of typing

```
    mvn clean install
```

into the terminal, all I needed to do was type

```
    mvn install -s settings.xml
```

Comment: Shipping with a settings.xml is really odd. People store local proxy etc. settings there.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exact same issue and it took couple of hours to debug. Wondering why this is not at all documented.

It looks like Hudson project is moved to eclipse.org hence in plugin pom.xml we need to changed parent declaration as below

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.eclipse.hudson.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>hudson-plugin-parent</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
</parent>
```

BTW in your machine if you first build the project for Jenkins and then Hudson you won't encounter this issue. This happens only when you are building Hudson plugin freshly where Jenkins dependent jars does not exist.